# R (DPLYR OU BASE) - Como remover linhas com base em uma condição

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Montei uma base de dados climáticos com 5,5 milhões de observações, só que percebi um problema.

Há estações duplicadas, são a mesma estação, porém possuem nomes diferentes por causa da fonte de dados onde foram retiradas.

Exemplo:
**Coluna:**  Estação;
**linha 1**: "A401";
**linha 2:** "Salvador zoológico A401"

Eu gostaria de uma luz para conseguir eliminar todas as linhas repetidas que contém o "A401" em comum. Por exemplo, queria que na saída, sobrasse apenas a linha com o código "A401" e todas as outras linhas com "Salvador zoológico A401" fossem excluídas.

Só que existe um porém, esse processo tem que ser automático, eu apenas quero indicar a string em comum que deve ser usada como condição para eliminação das outras linhas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A função abaixo elimina todas as linhas em que a string a manter é sub-string.

```
set.seed(2022)

Estação <- c("A401", "Salvador zoológico A401")
Estação <- c(Estação, "B201", "Outro Nome B201", paste0(LETTERS, "001"))
dados <- data.frame(Estação = sample(Estação, 100, TRUE))

eliminar <- function(x, col = "Estação", E) {
  i <- grepl(E, x[[col]])
  j <- nchar(x[[col]]) == nchar(E)
  y <- rbind(x[i & j, , drop = FALSE], x[!i, , drop = FALSE])
  row.names(y) <- NULL
  y
}
eliminar(dados, E = "A401")
eliminar(dados, E = "B201")
```

Comment: Resolvido de forma certeira, muito obrigado!!